# 1136: Incorrect number of arguments. Expected 0. on var ourShip:ship = new ship(stage);

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

Hi guys i am new to programming, I was following a tutorial on [As3 Flash Games](http://asgamer.com/2009/as3-flash-games-for-beginners-character-movement-handling-multiple-keypresses)

I came across a code in which it was written

```
var ourShip:ship = new ship(stage);
```

But it gave an error

```
1136: Incorrect number of arguments.  Expected 0.
```

I believe that the error it right but then what about the comments that the tutorial was awesome !

The as file which includes this code has in it

```
package
{
    //list of our imports these are classes we need in order to
    //run our application.
    import flash.display.MovieClip;
    import flash.display.Stage;

    //our Engine class it extends MovieClip
    public class engine extends MovieClip
    {

        //our constructor function. This runs when an object of
        //the class is created
        public function engine()
        {


            //create an object of our ship from the Ship class
            var ourShip:ship = new ship(stage);
            //add it to the display list
            stage.addChild(ourShip);
            ourShip.x = stage.stageWidth / 2;
            ourShip.y = stage.stageHeight / 2;
        }

    }

}
```

Also to tell that i changed the senocular package from

```
package come.asgamer.....{}
```

to

```
package utils{}
```

I did this as i made a single folder named utils which has senocular action script in it

I thought mabye the problem related to this

By the way if i change

```
var ourShip:ship = new ship(stage);
```

to

```
var ourShip:ship = new ship();
```

There is no result which means flash player displays the ship in middle as it is said

Ship action script file :

```
package
{

    import flash.display.MovieClip;
    import utils.KeyObject;
    import flash.ui.Keyboard;
    import flash.display.Stage;
    import flash.events.Event;


    public class ship extends MovieClip
    {
    private var stageRef:Stage;
    private var key:KeyObject;
    public function Ship(stageRef:Stage)
    {
    this.stageRef = stageRef;
    key = new KeyObject(stageRef);

    addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, loop, false, 0, true);
    }
    public function loop(e:Event) : void
        {
        if (key.isDown(Keyboard.LEFT)) 
                x -= 2;
            else if (key.isDown(Keyboard.RIGHT))
                x += 2;

            if (key.isDown(Keyboard.UP))
                y -= 2;
            else if (key.isDown(Keyboard.DOWN))
                y += 2;
        }
    }
}
```

Note : I completed the tutorial

Comment: How does the constructor in the `ship` class look like?

Comment: the issue is in the ship class, looks like it's not expecting the parameter you're sending to it

Comment: updated Please see the sip class

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Capitalize `ship`; that's what they're doing in the tutorial.  Try that and see if it works.

It is possible you are using a different class than the one you think you're using.  The class they provided is `Ship`, not `ship`, and in the code they provided for `Ship`, the constructor actually does have an a parameter:

```
package com.asgamer.basics1{

    import flash.display.MovieClip; import flash.display.Stage;
    import com.senocular.utils.KeyObject;
    import flash.ui.Keyboard;

    public class Ship extends MovieClip {

        private var stageRef:Stage;
        private var key:KeyObject;

        public function Ship(stageRef:Stage)
        {
            this.stageRef = stageRef;
            key = new KeyObject(stageRef);
        }

    }

}
```

If capitalizng `ship` doesn't work, you're moving in the right direction, but there may be another piece to the puzzle.

Comment: well i did not capitalize ship anywhere so it may not have any affect

where ever i saw Ship i changed it to ship so mabye it makes no difference, If it does please tell me and tell me how

Comment: Found the problem , i did not change one Ship to ship
corrected and it works